# Use Actions SDK for Google Assistant

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, actions-on-google

I am trying to use Actions SDK in my own Server, the actions that I made are showed in Google Assistant, but it's not working, the assistant just closes without showing any errors. This is my code:

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exps = express();
exps.use(bodyParser.json());

const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');

  const app = actionssdk({debug: true});

  const asyncTask = () => new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)
  );

  exps.post('/', function(request, response) {
    app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv) => {
      return asyncTask()
      .then(() =>  conv.ask('Hi, this is a test!'));
    });
   
  });
express().use(bodyParser.json(), app).listen(3000);
```

Request and Debug tabs
Both Errors and Response are empty.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to elaborate on what you mean by "it's not working"? Are you getting any errors in the logs for your server? If you are testing using the simulator, what are the contents of the "Request", "Response", "Debug", and "Error" tabs? When you test it, what exactly is happening?

Comment: I've updated it already, thanks

Comment: Are you testing this in the simulator? If so, can you update the question with the text of the "Request", "Response", "Debug", and "Error" tabs, and possibly a screen shot illustrating what is happening?

Comment: Yes, I am. I've updated it here, thanks

Comment: Pasting the text from those tabs help a lot more than a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are creating two *different* express objects. One gets mounted on the '/' path, but isn't setup to listen on any port. The other listens on a port, but doesn't have any paths setup for it to handle.

Changing your listener line to

```
exps.use(bodyParser.json(), app).listen(3000);
```

will make it so the express object where you've setup the '/' path will also be the one listening on the port.

It also appears that your webhook is listening at the '/' path, but you've specified the webhook in your actions.json file as using the '/node/' path. (It is a little difficult to read the screen shot - which is why we request you post the text and not a screen shot.) If you either change your webhook to listen to '/node/' or change the actions.json file to use '/', it should work.

Comment: Is it giving the same result on all the screens we were talking about?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses) suggests that you are attempting to call conv.ask() incorrectly. I would imagine you'd need something like this:

```
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({speech: 'Hi, this is a test!', text: 'Hi, this is a test!'}));
```

Comment: `conv.ask(string)` is a shortcut that will create a `SimpleResponse` object.